# Give Administrator rights to the application

Tags: windows, permissions

I use Inno Setup to generate the App installer. It succesfully installs the app, but I only can run it as Administrator. Since I don't want the user to right click the exe file and choose "Run as Administrator", I wonder if there is any simple way to grant admin privileges to the app itself, or conversly, grant those privileges by code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any simple way to grant admin privileges to the app itself

You need to provide a UAC manifest for your app that has its `requestedExecutionLevel` value set to `requireAdministrator`.

Create a text file with a `.manifest` file extension, and put the following XML in it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" name="MyAppAssemblyNameHere" type="win32"/>
  <description>My App Description</description>
  <!-- uncomment this to enable ComCtl v6 Visual Styles...
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Create a text file with a `.rc` file extension, and have it reference the `.manifest` file:

```
1 24 "myapp.manifest"
```

Compile the `.rc` file into a `.res` file using the command-line `brcc32.exe` utility.

```
brcc32 myapp.rc
```

In your project, go to **Project > Options > Application** and uncheck the "Enable runtime themes" checkbox.  This disables Delphi's default manifest, which only enables ComCtl v6 Visual Styles (which is why you need to enable styles manually in a custom manifest).

Now add the compiled `.res` file to your project, and build.

> or conversly, grant those privileges by code.

Not directly, no.  UAC elevation only happens at process startup.  Once a process has started running, it cannot be elevated dynamically.  However, what you CAN do is either:

1. call `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `"runas"` verb to launch another copy of your app with an extra command-line parameter (or a separate  `.exe`) to run your administrative logic as needed.  `"runas"` will elevate that process, even if it does not have a UAC manifest.  If your main app needs to wait for the admin process to finish, it can specify the `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` flag to `ShellExecuteEx()` and then use `WaitForSingleObject()` or related function to wait on the returned `HANDLE`, which will be signaled when the launched process exits.
2. move your administrative logic into a COM object that your main .exe can instantiate in an elevated state using the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) when needed.

This way, your main `.exe` does not need to use a `requireAdministrator` manifest, which you should always strive to avoid unless you REALLY need the entire app to run with admin rights.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Is by chance a way to command the Inno Setup to make all the necessary work, so the app will run from the "Program Files"?

Comment: An app can run from Program Files without needing to be elevated.  It needs elevation only if it has to access protected things at runtime, like writing files to Program Files. But in any case, if you create a manifest, it is best to embed it inside the app itself, but you *CAN* save it as a separate file next to the app in the same folder, and Inno could install such a file.  But I would not recommend that approach.

Comment: Bingo! If I tell Inno Setup to place the IO files in a separate folder, outside the Program Files folder, I suppouse that the exe file will run without elevation. Correct?

Comment: *WHERE* your exe file is placed has *NOTHING* to do with whether it *RUNS* elevated or not. As I said earlier, an exe file placed inside of Program Files can RUN without elevation. It just will not have administrative privileges, unless it has a UAC manifest specifying `requireAdministrator`, or the user runs it using "Run as Administrator".  I think you need to do some more research on how Windows security and UAC actually work.

Comment: You said that the program needs Admin priv in case it needs to have access to protected things. As the data files are inside the Program Files folder, I guess that Windows won't allow to write on them unless the exe has Adm priv. That, I figured out, was the reason why I get an access error when I run as a normal user.  Remy, I'm a simple an modest app developer. Is not my goal to be an expert on every TI subject. Hence I ask questions on this site, otherwise, there's no meaning to do so. If a problem arises, I ask help from the experts, as anybody else does. Be patient with me, please :).

Comment: Yes, you need admin rights to write files in Program Files. That does not mean you have to put your app in Program Files.  Two different things.  However, you should not be writing files in Program Files to begin with, unless you are writing an app installer/updater, or if you have any other choice.  Files created by your app should typically be written in the user's own Documents or AppData folder instead, or in the common Documents/AppData folder if multiple users need to access them.

Comment: @FlashThunder which part? Everything I have described still applies in Win10

Comment: I don't know, read some article about it... something about not setting guid? if it still works, great :) will check that later.

Comment: @FlashThunder there are no GUIDs involved in UAC. Either whatever you are reading is wrong, or you are misinterpreting it. Maybe you are thinking of the `supportedOS` GUIDs instead? That is a completely separate feature from UAC

Comment: I know it makes no sense, but generally Windows 10 doesn't make much sense